# How to include PHP variables in SwiftMailer body

Tags: php, html-email, swiftmailer

First of all, I can send emails perfectly fine with Swift Mailer. However, I want to include PHP variables into the body of the email.

This is what I've tried:

```
$link = "hi"; 

$message->setBody($link."Loser");
```

Why is this not working? :)

Comment: Have you tried  `$message->setBody(rawurlencode($link."Loser"));` ?

Comment: why would you rawurlencode(which does what it says) an email message body?

Comment: @PedroLobito Thank you! It worked...

Comment: @Dagon Yes. I'm making an activation email.

Comment: @PedroLobito You can post this as an answer and I'll mark it as the "Best Answer".

Comment: @MatthewMalan done! tks :)

Comment: *real* examples next time please it makes a huge diffirence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)

```
$link = "hi"; 
$message->setBody(rawurlencode($link." Winner :)"));
```